# Инициализация Коллекции при деплое приложения Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Хочу во время подъема сервера с приложением добавить в Лист все данные c БД, чтобы в дальнейшем с ними работать b запросы в БД при обновлении страницы. При размещении запроса в БД в конструктор или `static{}` выводит NPE, Лист в который я запрашиваю данные с БД пуст.

Как я понимаю, запрос поступает раньше, чем подключение к БД устанавливается.
Как мне это реализовать? И стоит ли так делать, если предположим в БД может размещаться миллион строк данных?
Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Довольно таки непонятно без кода, что вы имеете ввиду. Если вы хотите что то вроде кэша, то лучше использовать подходящие для этого инструменты, вроде `ehcache`.

Comment: Вы абсолютно правы, только ответ я уже нашёл.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> При размещении запроса в БД в конструктор или static{} выводит NPE

Это логичное и ожидаемое поведение: статический блок выполняется, если правильно помню, когда JVM загружает определение класса (имеется ввиду `.class`-файл) в память. Конструктор же выполняется при создании бина, но до того как Spring проинжектит в него все зависимости.

> Как мне это реализовать?

Вариантов много, но я советую, добавить метод с кодом для загрузки данных из БД и аннотировать его [аннотацией `@PostConstruct`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-postconstruct-and-predestroy-annotations)

> И стоит ли так делать, если предположим в БД может размещаться миллион строк данных?

Скорее всего нет, не стоит. Данные будут занимать память и, вероятно, не будут использоавться все время.